# Use loop to set property of all RadGrids in webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have several radgrids in my webform and I want to set all the *visible* property to false without having to specify the control name.

How can I do this with a loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery.

```
$("radgrids").prop("visible",false);
```

This will set all the radgrid element's visible property to false.
Hope this works. Don't forget to add the jQuery library.

Comment: Thanks, but it has to be server-side.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated way to do such a task in .NET

I think you will need a method like FindControlRecursive() that will recursively go through all controls on the page, and it will compare each control type with RadGrid, e.g.:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < form1.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        if ((form1.Controls[i]) is RadGrid)
            Response.Write(string.Format("found a grid with ID: {0}<br />", form1.Controls[i].ClientID));
    }
}
```

where this would need to be recursive, of course to get all controls on the page.